# How to use groupby and take the difference between the two groups?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, group-by, difference

Let say I have this simplified dataframe with three variables:

```
 ID    sample  test_result
 P1    Normal           9
 P2    Normal           7
 P3    Normal           2
 P1     Tumor           6
 P2     Tumor           5
 P3     Tumor           3
```

I want to know the difference between the normal and tumor `test_results`, but I am not sure how to approach it.

I have tried using groupby on `sample` column and then use the `diff()` method on `test_result` column but that did not work.

Here is what I have tried:

```
df.groupby('sample')['test_result'].diff()
```

The output I am expecting is like:

```
ID   test_result
P1             3 # the difference between P1 Normal and P1 Tumor (i.e. 9-6)
P2             2
P3            -1
```

Any idea how to tackle this?

Answer (score 2):

You can pivot `sample` column to the headers and then subtract between Normal and Tumor:

```
df.pivot('ID', 'sample', 'test_result').assign(diff = lambda x: x.Normal - x.Tumor)['diff']

#ID
#P1    3
#P2    2
#P3   -1
#Name: diff, dtype: int64
```

Comment: What if I have duplicate values in the `ID` column.  Is there a workaround to avoid `.pivot` error message: `ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape`?  Thanks!

Comment: In that case, you probably need to aggregate on ID and sample columns first.

Comment: Possibly `df.groupby(['ID', 'sample]).test_result.sum().reset_index()` or `...test_result.mean().reset_index()` depending on what you need, or check out `pivot_table` where you can specify an aggregate function and pivot.

Answer (score 0):

Or we can keep using `groupby`

```
df['New']=df.sort_values('ID').groupby('ID')['test_result'].diff()
df
Out[636]: 
   ID  sample  test_result  New
0  P1  Normal            9  NaN
1  P2  Normal            7  NaN
2  P3  Normal            2  NaN
3  P1   Tumor            6 -3.0
4  P2   Tumor            5 -2.0
5  P3   Tumor            3  1.0
df.dropna()
Out[637]: 
   ID sample  test_result  New
3  P1  Tumor            6 -3.0
4  P2  Tumor            5 -2.0
5  P3  Tumor            3  1.0


df.dropna()[['ID','New']]
Out[639]: 
   ID  New
3  P1 -3.0
4  P2 -2.0
5  P3  1.0
```